# Why the area of a parallelogram is base times height instead of length times width

Tags: geometry, area

The common formula for the area of a parallelogram is $\rm base\times height$. I'm trying to understand why it's not $\rm length\times width$. My thinking is that the total degrees of the $4$ angles inside the parallelogram is $360^\circ$. Why couldn't you just stand up a parallelogram so that it's a rectangle and then use the $\rm length\times width$ formula?

[image: example poorly drawn transformation]

Comment: Take a sheet of rubber, cut out a parallelogram, and transform it the way you've described. Does it feel like you're having to stretch it?

Comment: The area of a rectangle enclosing the parallelogram is no more than $h(l+w)$ so, by making $h$ very small, this area can be made arbitrarily small and much less than $lw$.  So  altering $h$ affects the area.

Comment: To see why your proposed formula breaks down: keep dragging that top line segment down, and in the process rotating those two lateral sides, the way you drew them. What does the area of the parallelogram look like when that bottom-left corner angle is just shy of $0°$? The whole thing is certainly disappearing. It can't possibly have the same area as the corresponding rectangle you drew.

Comment: If $\text{length}$ is the length of one side of the parallelogram, and $\text{width}$ is the perpendicular distance between that side and its opposite side, then the area of the parallelogram is $\text{length}\times \text{width}$.

Comment: @jvf tyty, this made it click!

Answer (score 2):

"Standing it up" as you put it, would change the area. Think of a large deck of cards, or a stack of post-it notes. When viewed from a side they may look like a rectangle. If you gradually push cards higher in the stack further out, then it might appear as a parallelogram from it's side. Of course the side of all of these cards will still have the same area after you push them, and critically, the stack will be of the same height. All you've done is shift the segments to their side.

When you "stand up" your parallelogram you are not shifting the cards into the stack again, you are stretching the entire deck, and modifying the area. When using base $\times$ height for the area you use the width of each segment, the base, and multiply it by the height of the stack.

In case you are still not convinced, consider the extreme case, when the rectangle is completely toppled over and becomes a straight line. Your length and width would be the same, but the area is 0, since it's just a line. Using base $\times$ height this makes sense, as the line has height 0, and thus area 0.